# Is there a way to load a certain html element and display a certain amount of characters from that element using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

WARNING: I am very new to PHP and don't know much about this code, I just found it online and modified the links and ID.

Not sure if this code is accurate, but I want to know if there is a way for me to display a certain html element from one page, for example a paragraph with the id "bioforfooter", on another page, such as my homepage, and limit the amount of characters in the string to about 310, while not cutting off the last word in the string. Also, I would like a hyperlink to be added right after the string that says "...Read More" (See Code). Here is the code I have so far, and it doesn't do anything.

PHP

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://example.com/about-me.php/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$raw = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);

$first_step = explode( '<p id="bioforfooter">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</p>" , $first_step[1] );
if (strlen($second_step[0]) > 310) {
     // truncate string
    $stringCut = substr($second_step[0], 0, 310);
    // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
    $result = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="http://www.example.com/about-me.php">Read More</a>'; 
}
```

On my homepage, I have

```
php echo $result;
```

in the empty paragraph tags that I made purely to display the preview of the bio and nothing is being displayed. Please help!

P.S. I initially used file_get_contents to include the "about-me.php" file, but the page load time exceeded 30 seconds, which is way too long.

Comment: basic debugging: did you check of `$raw` actually contains anything?

Comment: I am very new to PHP so I just found this code and changed some variables to what I thought would be correct, so I don't know if $raw contains anything. I don't know if you know of a better way to set this code up? @MarcB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not linking the result from your cUrl request, to the rest of your code.  Change `$content` to `$raw` and start from there.

You will probably find it easier to target a `<div>` directly using `DOMDocument()` than exploding the HTML.  Something like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query('//div[@id="bioforfooter"]');
$div = $div->item(0);
```

Comment: Probably should have been a comment, but you are right so what the heck

Comment: I haven't finished yet.. ;)